# Show that $A \subseteq B$ if and only if every subset of A is a subset of B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show that $A \subseteq B$ if and only if every subset
of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

So I know I have to prove this in both directions but this is what I got so far:

If if every subset
of $A$ is a subset of $B$ then, $A \subseteq B$ .

Let $U=$ be the union of all the subsets of $A$

Assume that $A\not\subseteq B$ by definition $U\not\subseteq B$

Then there exists an arbitrary subset of $U$ that is not a subset to $B$ by definition of subset negation

Now we have shown that not every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$

Similar the other way?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, since $A$ is a subset of $A$ we conclude $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Conversely suppose $A\subseteq B$ take a subset $X$ of $A$, then every element of $X$ is in $A$, but since every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, we conclude every element of $X$ is an element of $B$, so $X\subseteq B$

Comment: so this is the whole proof? forwards and backwards?

Comment: It depends, how do you feel about it?

Comment: I mean the first part sounds a bit weird but it makes sense that every set is a subset of itself and the second part also holds because X was an arbitrary subset of A?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, every subset of $A$   is subset of $B$ means $\forall x, x \epsilon P(A) \implies x \epsilon P(B)$. Now, $A \epsilon P(A).$So, $A \epsilon P(B)$. That means $A ⊆ B$.

Hope you proceed for converse by simillar method.

Comment: Assume  A⊆B let X be arbitrary subset of A then x element of power set(A) implies X element of power series (B) since X was arbitrary it holds all subsets of A are subsets of B?

Comment: exactly.It's true.